# PHP Array Looping & Exploding

Tags: php, arrays

I'm not very experienced in using PHP, but I'm having a hard time thinking of a way to do this. I'm reading from a file and exploding on ":" as you can see here.

```
<?php
$datainfo = file('data.txt');
for($i = 0; $i < count($datainfo); $i++){
$expdata = explode(':', $datainfo[$i]);
}

?>
```

The issue is that I need to reference specific indexes of the resulted explosion like this.

```
<p> <?php echo $expdata[1] ?> </p>
```

I'm getting back an array of the last line inside the data.txt file. I know why It's happening, I just don't know how to get what I want here. (Sorry Very New). Data.txt contain the following.

```
name:Octopod Juice Stand
balance:20
price:0.5
customers:12
starting:2014-05-26
end: 2014-09-01
juice:15.25
fruit:10
```

Comment: Show the contents of data.txt

Comment: Do `$expdata[]` instead of `$expdata`. You are reassigning the variable with each loop thats why you get the last line only.

Comment: When I did that, it just echos out the word "Array" so I'm assuming it 's empty for some reason.

Comment: Do `print_r($expdata)` instead of echoing and see the array dump.

Comment: Because `$expdata` will be a two-dimensional array, so `$expdata[1]` will refer to `array('balance', '20')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your code to

```
<?php
$datainfo = file('data.txt');
$expdata = array();

for($i = 0; $i < count($datainfo); $i++){
    $expdata[] = explode(':', $datainfo[$i]);
}

?>
```

And then to get the first label.

```
<p><?php echo $expdata[0][0]; ?></p>
```

Or the first value

```
<p><?php echo $expdata[0][1]; ?></p>
```

Comment: Yeah, thank you for this, I noticed this reading one of the comments. I'm pretty tired and didn't even think about it being two dimensional.